# Obsidian scheduler for running linux scripts

Tags: linux, ubuntu, scheduled-tasks, scheduler

I am using obsidian scheduler for scheduling various jobs written on a linux box. And trying to call shell scripts with a nohup command like

**UPDATE 1:**

```
nohup ./script.sh  > output.txt &
```

**UPDATE 2**

This is the error when i use nohup.

```
nohup: failed to run command â./test.sh &>./load.log &â: No such file or directory
```

I dont see anything writing to the output file. 
And secondly how can i verify that it is using nohup command to execute the script.

Thanks

Comment: Did you mean `nohup script.sh > output.txt &` ?

Comment: Yes, I  have updated the question.

Comment: Did your script provide output? Can you start it without nohup and redirection?

Comment: Yes, it does. When i run it on command line i see an output, was expecting that to work with obsidian also.

Comment: Hmmmm... Maybe results is accessible by Job History page, didn't it?

Comment: Yes i can see the raw output on the history page. But i want it to write to an output file.

Comment: Maybe in this case you should use obsidian api for getting output (by obsidian opinion :) )?

Comment: Btw if you wrap this script in another one -- problem is same?

Comment: I dont want to have a wrapper script ...not a viable solution since I want to call lots of scripts.

Comment: Just for test. If this workaround can be done , you can write mega wrapper for all your cases